# phoenix canary not_found handler

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I use [canary lib](https://github.com/cpjk/canary) in my phoenix app.

I wrote in config.exs:

```
config :canary, repo: MyApp.Repo,
      unauthorized_handler: {MyApp.Helpers, :handle_unauthorized},
      not_found_handler: {MyApp.Helpers, :handle_not_found}
```

and created helper:

```
defmodule MyApp.Helpers do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  require Logger
  import Plug.Conn

  def handle_unauthorized(conn) do
    conn
    |> put_status(401)
    |> put_view(MyApp.ErrorView)
    |> render("401.json")
    |> halt
  end

  def handle_not_found(conn) do
    conn
    |> put_status(404)
    |> put_view(MyApp.ErrorView)
    |> render("404.json")
    |> halt
  end
end
```

my abilities.ex:

```
defimpl Canada.Can, for: MyApp.User do
  alias MyApp.Operation
  alias MyApp.User

  def can?(user, action, operation = %Operation{})  when action in [:show, :update, :delete] do
    IO.puts "check ability for operation"
    if operation.user_id == user.id do
      IO.puts "success"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def can?(subject, action, resource) do
    raise """
    Unimplemented authorization check for User!  To fix see below...

    Please implement `can?` for User in #{__ENV__.file}.

    The function should match:

    subject:  #{inspect subject}

    action:   #{action}

    resource: #{inspect resource}
    """
  end
end
```

And unauthorized_handler works fine. But not_found_handler does not work.

```
[error] #PID<0.709.0> running MyApp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/v1/operations/11
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) Unimplemented authorization check for User!  To fix see below...

Please implement `can?` for User in /home/mars/phoenix_projects/my_app/lib/abilities.ex.
```

if I add to my abilities.ex this function:

```
  def can?(user, action, nil) do
    IO.puts "check ability for nil"
    false
  end
```

If the resource is not found, I will be called handle_unauthorized

If I leave only

```
def can?(user, action, operation = %Operation{}) when action in [:show, :update, :delete] do
```

Then I will have an error

```
(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Canada.Can.MyApp.User.can?/3
```

I do not understand how I need to write a function for this case

Upd: full error message:

```
[error] #PID<0.427.0> running MyApp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/v1/operations/11
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) Unimplemented authorization check for User!  To fix see below...

Please implement `can?` for User in /home/mars/phoenix_projects/my_app/lib/abilities.ex.

The function should match:

subject:  %MyApp.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">, operations: [%MyApp.Operation{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "operations">, balance: 1.3e3, categories: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :categories is not loaded>, id: 1, inserted_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:00:38.727984], name: "new name", updated_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:45:08.860944], users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>}, %MyApp.Operation{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "operations">, balance: 0.0, categories: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :categories is not loaded>, id: 2, inserted_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:00:59.396742], name: "test1", updated_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:00:59.396747], users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>}, %MyApp.Operation{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "operations">, balance: 0.0, categories: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :categories is not loaded>, id: 3, inserted_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:01:56.845078], name: "test0", updated_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:01:56.845085], users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>}, %MyApp.Operation{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "operations">, balance: 0.0, categories: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :categories is not loaded>, id: 4, inserted_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:04:25.647952], name: "testtt", updated_at: ~N[2017-04-15 15:04:25.647958], users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>}], confirmation_token: nil, confirmed: false, id: 1, inserted_at: ~N[2017-04-15 14:58:48.263515], login: "test user0", password: nil, password_confirmation: nil, password_hash: "$2b$12$8yt6WNBt5hyxZE1MqiZtX.YRuReOuy4zom1imQvK2Q.Dw6pc8iNSG", reset_password_token: nil, sessions: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :sessions is not loaded>, updated_at: ~N[2017-04-15 14:58:48.268564]}

action:   show

resource: nil

        (my_app) lib/abilities.ex:43: Canada.Can.MyApp.User.can?/3
        (canary) lib/canary/plugs.ex:214: Canary.Plugs.do_authorize_resource/2
        (canary) lib/canary/plugs.ex:187: Canary.Plugs.authorize_resource/2
        (canary) lib/canary/plugs.ex:274: Canary.Plugs.do_load_and_authorize_resource/2
        (my_app) web/controllers/v1/operation_controller.ex:1: MyApp.V1.OperationController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (my_app) lib/my_app/endpoint.ex:1: MyApp.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (my_app) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: MyApp.Router.dispatch/2
        (my_app) web/router.ex:1: MyApp.Router.do_call/2
        (my_app) lib/my_app/endpoint.ex:1: MyApp.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (my_app) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: MyApp.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (my_app) lib/my_app/endpoint.ex:1: MyApp.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /home/mars/phoenix_projects/my_app/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? It should also print the actual values of subject, action, and resource, which would help make this question clearer.

Comment: @Dogbert, added

Comment: Its been a while since I used Canary. I would suggest you try returning `true` for a nil resource. I believe this will allow the not found code to run. Checkout the implement of the [Canary Plugs](https://github.com/cpjk/canary/blob/master/lib/canary/plugs.ex) for more information.

Comment: @StevePallen, Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return true for the `can?(_, _, nil)` function clause, this will allow the authorization to pass and the handle_not_found plug to set the `conn` properly.